# how to process multiple foreach statements separately?

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement, foreach, operator-precedence

I am very new at PowerShell and I don't even know how to Google this properly.

This is what I'm trying to do: run some commands at multiple computers.

I can get them to run command1 at computerA, then command2 at computerA, then command3 at Computer A... then command1 at computerB command2 at computerB...and so forth

But I want to run command1 at all the computers
then command2 at all the computers
then command3 ...etc

So this is how it is right now:
1A
2A
3A
1B
2B
3B
1C
2C
3C...

Is is possible to do this in the if $state -eq 'Start' statement?

1A
1B
1C
2A
2B
2C
3A
3B
3C... without creating another function?

I don't want to reverse everything, just the "start" statement that I need to follow that pattern.

This is my basically what I have right now:

```
$Computers = "ComputerA","ComputerB","ComputerC"
function Set-CService {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('Start','Stop','Restart','Install')]
    [string]$State,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [array]$Computers
)

process {
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

If ($state -eq 'Start') {
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {Write-Host "statement1 on $Computer"}
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {Write-Host "statement2 on $Computer"}
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {Write-Host "statement3 on $Computer"}
}


foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
If ($State -eq 'Stop') {Write-Host "It is stopping on $Computer"}

If ($state -eq 'Restart') {
Write-Host "Restart statement1 on $Computer"
write-host "Restart statement2 on $Computer"
Write-Host "Restart statement3 on $Computer"}

If ($State -eq 'Install') {
Write-Host "Install statement1 on $Computer"
write-host "Install statement2 on $Computer"
Write-Host "Install statement3 on $Computer"}
                            }                                
        }
            }

$Computers | Set-CService -State Start
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command` will allow you to do this on all servers in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I tried Invoke-Command and got it to work outside of the function, but when I pipe the computers to the function, it always processes each computer no matter what. I use the same function for different sets of computers and they change by a variable. That's why I have to use a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Invoke-Command -AsJob` to invoke the remote work loads as background jobs:

```
If ($state -eq 'Start') {
  # Kick off remoting jobs on each computer in $Computers
  $jobs = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -Scriptblock {
    Write-Host "statement1 on $env:ComputerName"
    Write-Host "statement2 on $env:ComputerName"
    Write-Host "statement3 on $env:ComputerName"
  } -AsJob

  # Wait for jobs to succeed, then receive the output
  $jobs |Receive-Job -Wait
}
```

Comment: No, all three statements will be processed independently by the target machines. If you want to ensure stmt 1 has run on all computers before you start stmt 2, simply repeat `Invoke-Command -AsJob`/`Receive-Job -Wait` for each separate statement

Comment: Thank you. That works for what I need. If I start that as a job, does it wait until Statement 1 is done on all computers before moving on to statement 2...and so forth?

Comment: Sorry my question got deleted. Thank you for your help! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.  Each statement runs in parallel on all 3 computers, but waits before going on to the next statement.

```
$computers = echo a001 a002 a003
$statements = {Write-Host "statement1 on $env:Computername"},
  {Write-Host "statement2 on $env:computername"},
  {Write-Host "statement3 on $env:Computername"}
foreach ($statement in $statements) {
  invoke-command $computers $statement
}

statement1 on A001
statement1 on A002
statement1 on A003
statement2 on A001
statement2 on A002
statement2 on A003
statement3 on A003
statement3 on A002
statement3 on A001
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, It works if I put the operation outside the function. But when I do `If $State -eq 'Start' foreach $Statement in $statements {invoke-command $computers statement}` It still processes all tasks on each computer before moving on to the next. I think because I pipe the computers to the function, that's why it's doing that?